# Обособление (отделение) причастного оборота

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Тогда сможет проявиться огромный и с каждым днем нарастающий религиозный фактор.*

Не надо ли добавить запятых?

Comment: Простите, а где у нас деепричастие?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не надо, тут у вас два однородных члена, объединённых союзом **`и`**, который исключает запятые.

Запятая потребовалась бы, имей предложение следующую синтаксическую форму

> Тогда сможет проявиться огромный религиозный фактор, нарастающий с каждым днем.